# How to log exception as structured JSON with NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

This is the code:

```
try
{
    throw new AssertionException("This is exceptional");
}
catch (AssertionException ex)
{
    // Rider nags me to write Error logs with exceptions this way
    logger.Error(ex, "Houston, we have a problem!"); 
}
```

And the config is this:

```xml
<targets async="false">
    <target name="NoPiiLog" xsi:type="Memory">
        <layout type="SuppressPiiJsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="2"
                excludeProperties="UserId,EmailId" excludeEmptyProperties="true">
            <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
            <attribute name="level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
            <attribute name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
            <attribute name="exception">
                <layout type="JSonLayout"  includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="2"
                        excludeProperties="UserId,EmailId" excludeEmptyProperties="true" />
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="Properties">
                <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="2"
                        excludeEmptyProperties="true"/>
            </attribute>
        </layout>
    </target>
```

SuppressPiiJsonLayout is a class I wrote and registered that takes the final JSON and replaces all the PII key values with "*****". What I can't do is to log the exceptionunless I include "{exception}" in the message string and the exception object in the params, like this:

```
 logger.Error(ex, "Houston, we have a problem! {exception}", ex);
```

This is because the exception does not get into the Params or the Properties of the LogEvent, it is in an Exception member on the LogEvent.  The docs don't cover structured logging of exceptions. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions

So that you don't think my suppressor is screwing things up, here is that code:

```
[Layout("SuppressPiiJsonLayout")]
[ThreadAgnostic]
[ThreadSafe]
public class SuppressPiiJsonLayout : NLog.Layouts.JsonLayout
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This digs thru the JObject and replaces the values with "*****".  It recurses thru all the JObjects it
    ///   finds along the way, replacing the values in ExcludeProperties
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logEvent">The logging event.</param>

    private void CleanKeys(JObject obj)
    {
        foreach (var entry in obj)
        {
            if(this.ExcludeProperties.Contains(entry.Key))
            {
                obj[entry.Key] = "*****";
            }
            else
            {
                if (obj[entry.Key] is JObject)
                {
                    this.CleanKeys((JObject)obj[entry.Key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This intercepts the rendering of the formatted message after it is turned into JSON and then cleans
    ///   all of the "ExcludeProperties" from the JSON about to be outputted, recursing thru all the objects
    ///   it finds.  Unlike the ExcludeProperties of the JSONLayout which is practically useless.  It might not be
    ///   the most efficient thing, but considering how immutable anonymous objects are, it is definitely the
    ///   only way I found to implement it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logEvent">The logging event.</param>
    /// <param name="target"><see cref="StringBuilder"/> for the result</param>
    protected override void RenderFormattedMessage(LogEventInfo logEvent, StringBuilder target)
    {
        var intercept = new StringBuilder();
        base.RenderFormattedMessage(logEvent, intercept);
        var j = JObject.Parse(intercept.ToString());

        this.CleanKeys(j); // Remove all the ExcludeProperties it finds recursively
        target.Append(j.ToString(Formatting.None)); // And then pass the modified version to the target for writing
    }
}
```

I guess I could alter this code to make ex.Exception a named parameter, but it seems like NLOG should already be handling this so I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: I'd recommend decorating your classes with a custom attribute and writing a Json.Net converter instead.  It'll make your code self-documenting and you are no longer dependent on NLog to get it right.

Answer (score 6):

Yes the [LogEventInfo.Exception](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer) is not included in [LogEventInfo.Properties](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer), so it will not be included when using `includeAllProperties="true"`:

Instead of doing this:

```xml
<attribute name="exception">
    <layout type="JSonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="2"
    excludeProperties="UserId,EmailId" excludeEmptyProperties="true" />
</attribute>
```

Then you can do this (`encode="false"` is to avoid encoding the json-output from `format=@`):

```xml
<attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=@}" encode="false" />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#output-captured-properties